# md-contact-chips with complex data object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-material

I have a complex object like attached below. I want to implement tag functionality like in stackoverflow using angular material-contact-chip [codepen link](http://codepen.io/gnomeontherun/pen/JdXyNr). Can someone help me on getting this done 

`{
    "statusReason": "OK",
    "responseHeaders": {
        "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
        "Server": "Apache-Coyote\/1.1",
        "Date": "Sat, 12 Dec 2015 15:22:00 GMT",
        "Content-Type": "application\/json"
    },
    "isSuccessful": true,
    "responseTime": 4,
    "totalTime": 6,
    "rows": [{
        "doc": {
            "over16": true,
            "address3": "Waterside",
            "familyName": "tlor",
            "ldapId": 2,
            "acceptedTermsAndConditions": true,
            "id": 2,
            "email": "kevin@gmail.com",
            "status": {
                "name": "Active",
                "id": 2
            }
        }
    }, {
        "doc": {
            "over16": true,
            "address3": "Waterside",
            "familyName": "sarha",
            "ldapId": 2,
            "acceptedTermsAndConditions": true,
            "id": 2,
            "email": "ain@gmail.com",
            "status":`{
                "name": "Active",
                "id": 2
            }

```
    }
}],
"statusCode": 200
```

}

Comment: And exactly what is the problem?

Comment: When I am searching with a keyword array of objects comes as a response i.e rows. In the autocomplete dropdown for the material-contact-chip "md-contacts: will be set with "rows" array object. md-contact-name accepts only string. But in my case i have "doc" object and inside that I have properties. I want to familyname to be displayed in the autocomplete dropdown.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample please?

Comment: Here is the code  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyjpeN

Comment: Ok out of the box are aware that you have an error on line 60? Check console for that codepen.